# Vuex getter не передает значение в computed свойство

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

столкнулся с проблемой что геттер для vuex не передает значение.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    arCityWeater: null
  },
  actions: {
    addCity: async ({commit}, cityName) => {
      console.log('ww')
      commit('ADD_CITY', cityName)
    },
    GET_WEATER_ON_COORD: async ({commit}, payload) => {
      let {data} = await axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='
        + payload.latitude
        + '&lon='
        + payload.longitude + '&appid='
        + 'e9c75f6dc1027a3488ea4818c1932495').catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
      if (data.cod == 200) {
        commit('ADD_CITY', data);
      }
      console.log('zzz');
      console.log(payload); //значение нормальное
      console.log(data); //значение нормальное
      console.log('mmm');
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_CITY: (state, payload) => {
      console.log('gg')
      console.log(payload) //значение нормальное
//        state.arCityWeater.push(payload)
      state.arCityWeater = payload;
      console.log(state.arCityWeater) //значение нормальное
      console.log('ss')
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getArCityWeater: state => {
      console.log('ff')
      console.log(state) // null
      console.log(state['arCityWeater']) // null
      console.log(state.arCityWeater)  // null
      console.log('oo')
      return state.arCityWeater
    },
    isCityWeater(state) {
      console.log('yy')
      console.log(state.arCityWeater)
      //console.log(state.arCityWeater.length)
      console.log('uu')
      //return state.arCityWeater.length > 0
    }
  },
  modules: {
    // Это приложение слишком маленькое для модулей...
  }
});
```

и следовательно получаю значение в computed

```
computed: {
  arCityWeather() {
    console.log('ee')
    console.log(this.$store.getters.getArCityWeater) //null
    console.log('nn');
    return this.$store.getters.getArCityWeater; //null
  },
},
```

Comment: А так установить какое-то отличное от null значение вы не забыли?

Comment: В плане? В компоненте я дергаю actions, который в свою очередь вызывает mutations, в котором задается значение отличное от null, но в геттере уже приходит null

Comment: Попробуйте инициализировать стэйт значением не null, например `arCityWeater: {}`. Если не поможет, то присваивание замените на `Vue.set`.

Comment: @ДенисШевченко проверьте проходил ли мутация

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei Менял значение и на пустой объект, не помогло
попробовал `vue.$set(this.arCityWeater, 0, payload)`, но выпала ошибка о том что такого свойства не существует, и честно не совсем понял как это работает.

Comment: @adrug Да проходит, но по логам я вижу что мутация отрабатывает позже чем computed свойство, может это как то влияет?

Comment: Потому что надо в доках смотреть как и что работает.
Не `vue.$set`, а `vue.set`. 
Присваивание через вызов метода `set` гарантирует реактивность.

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei Попробовал `Vue.set(store, state.arCityWeater , payload)`
вроде ошибки в консоль не падают, но значение так и не доходит до computed

Comment: В мутации: `Vue.set(state, 'arCityWeater', payload)`

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei попробовал, значение даже не присваевается в мутаторе, то есть после этой команды пытаюсь вывести лог значение `arCityWeater` но оно пустое.

Comment: Денис, вы используете при отладке vue devtools?

Comment: Я перестал понимать происходящее )) Пилите песочницу и воспроизводите ваш код. Иначе это пальцем в небо все. 99,99% дело в невнимательности.

Comment: @adrug,  да я использую, правда не до конца освоил его.

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei Я понял вас, буду переделывать скорее много грязи в коде, спасибо большое)) А еще вопрос в целом концептуально я правильно подошел к решению задачи что код запроса лежит в vuex, а не в компоненте?

Comment: Отвечу за товарища. Хорошая практика чтобы компонент работал с гетерами и экшенами.  Собственно любое изменение состояния должно происходить через мутации.

Comment: Касательно vuejs devtools.  С его помощью можно легко отслеживать текущее состояние. Какие мутации уже прошли. Очень удобная штука. Советую использовать ее при отладке вместо множества `console.log`

Comment: @adrug Спасибо большое) Я решил с нуля все переписать, и все заработало, так что скорее всего просто была где то логическая ошибка.